# How can I call an in-class function from an in-class button?

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically, I'm trying to make a GUI for a turtle to draw shapes. I have made a number of functions that will draw specific shapes or do specific actions, but when trying to make buttons that call those functions, I keep getting an error saying that the functions don't exist.

Here's a snippet of my code that contains the problem:

The initial code was this:

```
import turtle 
import tkinter as tk 
car = turtle.Turtle()

class Car:
    def __init__(self, color = "black"):
        car.color(color)

    def big_funny(self):
        car.right(90)
        car.write("     I")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     Have")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     Crippling")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     Depression")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     c:")
        
        turtle.done()

    GUI = tk.Tk()
    GUI.geometry("300x300")
    GUI.title("Car thing!!~~~~")
    text = tk.Label(GUI, text = "Select a button for the thing to draw", anchor = "center")
    text.grid(row = 1)

    funnyButton = tk.Button(GUI, text = "Funny", command=lambda:big_funny())
    funnyButton.grid(row=2)
```

On the surface, everything works well, it's just the function call that's messing everything up. I have tried the following to the command parameter in funnyButton:

```
    command=lambda:self.big_funny()  ## 'self' not defined

    funnyVar = big_funny()  ## missing required argument: 'self', but 'self'
   # does not exist if i add it
    command=funnyVar

    command=lambda:Car.big_funny()  ## "Car" does not exist??
    command=lambda:car.Car.big_funny()  ## Doesn't work either
```

I can't really write out everything I've tried, but I've tried a lot. I've been troubleshooting and trial-and-erroring for over an hour and a half now. I am very frustrated and very tired, so any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: What is this class trying to do? You've got a class called `Car` whose constructor initializes a *global* variable called `car` (which is a `turtle.Turtle`), and whose class body (executed once, not once per instance) sets up a tkinter window at startup. I think you may be severely misunderstanding what a *class* is. The code snippet you've shown never initializes an instance of this class, so it's very true that, at the point in the code you're asking about, there really is no `self`.

Comment: I might not know what I'm doing in this regard, but Python keeps asking for the positional argument 'self', and I can't get the button to call the function regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you used class in your code is wrong.

#### The Easy Fix:

The most simple thing you can do to make your code run is moving what you wrote inside your class into the `__init__` function (+ adding `.mainloop` to the tkinter GUI) and create a class instance to start the initializing.

So something like that:

```
import turtle 
import tkinter as tk 
car = turtle.Turtle()

class Car:
    def __init__(self, color = "black"):
        car.color(color)
        GUI = tk.Tk()
        GUI.geometry("300x300")
        GUI.title("Car thing!!~~~~")
        text = tk.Label(GUI, text = "Select a button for the thing to draw", anchor = "center")
        text.grid(row = 1)

        funnyButton = tk.Button(GUI, text = "Funny", command=lambda:self.big_funny())
        funnyButton.grid(row=2)
        GUI.mainloop()

    def big_funny(self):
        car.right(90)
        car.write("     I")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     Have")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     Crippling")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     Depression")
        car.forward(75)
        car.left(1)
        car.right(1)
        car.write("     c:")
        
        turtle.done()

Car()
```

But, that is not the way I would write it.

Comment: Holy crud!! That was super simple. I don't know why I didn't have the class initializing code inside of the initializing function 
Thank you!!

Comment: Happy to help :)